# How to wait for WebClient response on timeout in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-async

I have a `WebClient` that I want to stop and provide a fallback value after a certain `timeout`.

```
webClient.post()
    .uri(path)
    .bodyValue(body)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(type)
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
    .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(provideFallbackValue())); //not only timeout, but any failure
```

Anyways, I would like to continue waiting for the response in another background thread in case of a `TimeoutException` (at least for let's say for another 60s), and still process the response then async.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not do the same request again with longer timeout in a new thread, when the first request fails after short timeout ?

Comment: I cannot repeat the request. I can only wait.

Comment: Then wrap the 75s request into a thread with https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is change the point of view of this code. Instead of wait for additional 60 seconds in another thread start immediately the new thread and work asynchronously.

If the answer from the second thread arrives in 15 seconds or less you can reply immediately. Otherwise, send the message related to the error, but you still have active the call until 60 seconds.

---

Here is a code that can do that:

```
private Future<YourClass> asyncCall() {
    ...
    // Put here the async call with a timeout of 60 seconds
    // This call can be sync because you are already in a secondary thread
}


// Main thread
try {
    Future<YourClass> future = executors.submit(() -> asyncCall());
    YourClass result = future.get(15, TimeUnit.SECOND);
    // Result received in less than 15 seconds
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // Handle timeout of 15 seconds
}
```

Comment: But that would imply I have to send the request out 2 times directly (one thread with 15s, and one with 60s timeout)? I have to avoid that. I can only send out this request once.

Comment: No, you can send the request just once in a separated thread, then on the main thread wait for 15 seconds on a lock. The second thread will notify when the end of the call is reached. If the call ends before 15 seconds your main thread will be notified and you have the answer immediately. If the answer needs more than 15 seconds your main thread restarts without the answer, but the secondary thread still be active until the 60 seconds

Comment: Could you give an example on this? I mean, because `webClient` calls are async anyways, they would return immediately. So how can I create an outer timeout thread around them?

Comment: Yes, just added to the answer

Comment: Thanks, but how can I then convert the webClient call (that returns a `Mono`) into a Future?

Comment: I testet your suggestion, which works. Thanks for this! Anyways I'd be more interested in a solution that simply works with wrapped `Monos`, instead of starting to introduce `Futures`